How to update custom metrics value based on other metrics in Google cloud monitoring?
I want to create a custom metric in Google Cloud Monitoring which is a time series. The value will be based on other existing metrics(For example, "MetricC" is sum of 2 other metrics "MetricA + MetricB", computed every hour).


How to do this using Cloud Monitoring API in Python? Will the values be updated every hour automatically in Cloud Monitoring? Thanks.

What is the end goal here ? Alerting ? or just to create the metric ?

In achieving this, you may start with preparing the requirements such as installing the google-cloud-monitoring library
pip install google-cloud-monitoring

Import the necessary libraries and authenticate your Cloud Monitoring client
After installing the pre-requisites, you can create your custom metric by creating MetricDesciptor as an example for objects specifying the custom metric's details.
Once the metric was created, then define a function to calculate the values from the source metrics.
And to achieve the automatic hourly updates, you'll need to schedule the logic to run every hour. This can be done using a cron job, Cloud Functions, or other scheduling methods outside of the monitoring API itself.
You can check this documentation by Arpana Mehta for reference. The article has 3 parts.

As far as i know, and based on the docs, GCP doesn't offer automatic population of datapoints for user-defined/custom metrics.
However, if the main goal is alerting, and not just creating a metric, there's a way to create alerts, based on relations between existing metrics.
Here is how you can create a some_job failure rate metric for example, using PromQL (via PrometheusQueryLanguageCondition) :
from google.cloud.monitoring_v3 import AlertPolicy


# Set params
duration = "900s"
evaluation_interval = "900s"
query = "sum(rate(dataproc_googleapis_com:cluster_job_failed_count{monitored_resource=\"cloud_dataproc_cluster\",job_type=\"job_name\"}[15m]))/sum(rate(dataproc_googleapis_com:cluster_job_failed_count{monitored_resource=\"cloud_dataproc_cluster\"}[15m]))"

# Set PromQL condition
AlertPolicy.Condition.PrometheusQueryLanguageCondition(
    duration=duration, 
    evaluation_interval=evaluation_interval, 
    query=query
)

# Go on to create your Alerting policy based on the previous condition

Here is the GCP doc on how to create an Alerting Policy via Python API
If you need the metric and it's datapoints, not just the alerting, there's the option, where you create your custom metric (see doc here), but fill it with your own data points (via Cloud Run Functions for example). You can fetch data from Metric A and Metric B periodically (or event-driven), add them up, and push it to the custom metric.
Of course, installing necessary packages such as google-cloud-monitoring  is not to be dismissed.
More on how to push datapoints to a custom metrics, here and here.
